# TADoConnection and pooling

Tags: delphi

I am working on all application that uses multiple threads that access a sql server 2005 db, i am currently using implicit connections by setting up the connection string property of the TADOQuery object, but that seems to open a lot of connections to the database. We need to reduce the number of connections that a single instance keeps open, so

1. is there any kind of connection pooling available in tadoconnection library, and how can i enable it and set it limits.
2. if not then whats the recommended way of reducing and reusing connections to the database, so that the application scales well.

i would appreciate any opinions or thoughts..

many thanks

Comment: Try adding  MultipleActiveResultSets=True   into your connection string. Adding this as a comment because I'm not sure if it'll work on Delphi.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this is the whole purpose behind the `TADOConnection` component, is to pool your database connections in one place rather than creating multiple `TADOQuery` components with their own connections. However answers here describe some strange workings of ADO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, ADO database connections to SQL Server are pooled with no work needed by you. The pooling behavior can be altered by your connection string. What's your connection string look like?

Just keep your connection string exactly the same and create/free a ADO Connection within your thread and let the ADO runtime handle the pooling.  The number of connections per process will usually equal to the max number of "recent" simultaneous connections plus a few for a buffer.

Comment: i know that ado.net does connection pooling by default, but does TADOConnection of delphi does that too ?, do you have any links to any related documentation ?

Comment: TADOConnection is Borland/CodeGear wrapping of Microsoft's OLEDB interfaces. Here's a link http://blogs.msdn.com/selvar/archive/2007/11/10/ole-db-resource-pooling.aspx.   If you look at ADODB you'll see this wrapping of that Borland did.  You could import the typelib's yourself and go direct, but it's much, much easier to use TADOxxx components.

Answer (score 4):

Another reason for increased number of connections is multiple open queries active on the same connection.

Say you have code like

```
db := TAdoConnection.Create()
qry1 := TAdoQuery.Create();
qry2 := TAdoQuery.Create();

qry1.connection := db;
qry2.connection := db;

qry1.SQL.Text := 'select * from whatever';

qry1.open;
while not qry1.eof do
begin
  x := qry1.fieldbyname('fld').AsString;
  qry2.SQL.Text := 'select * from elsewhere where SomeField='+ QuotedStr(x);
  qry2.Open;
  ..do something..
  qry2.Close;

  qry1.Next;
end;
```

The qry2.Open() will cause another connection to be created *which is not pooled*

If you have code like this, store the results of qry1 to a local place and then do the work of qry2.  In this case, you will maintain only one connection.

In rough terms this looks more like:

```
db := TAdoConnection.Create()
qry1 := TAdoQuery.Create();
qry2 := TAdoQuery.Create();
str := TStringList.Create();

qry1.connection := db;
qry2.connection := db;

qry1.SQL.Text := 'select * from whatever';

qry1.open;
while not qry1.eof do
begin
  x := qry1.fieldbyname('fld').AsString;
  str.Add(x);
  qry1.Next;
end;
qry1.Close;

for i := 0 to str.Count-1 do
begin
  qry2.SQL.Text := 'select * from elsewhere where SomeField='+ QuotedStr(str[i]);
  qry2.Open;
  ..do something..
  qry2.Close;
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting the TADOConnection component on the DataModule and using that from all other ADO components on the datamodule should already reduce a lot of the connections.
If the application is using a great number of datamodules, it's possible to make these datamodules share the same connection at runtime.

Comment: in my case several threads would accessing the datamodule, would tadoconnection open multiple queries simultaneously ?

Comment: If you want to use a datamodule from threads, it would make sense to create and destroy an instance of the datamodule in the thread, so each thread has it's own datamodule to work with. Then you're sure to have a connection per thread, and that values in parameters and fields won't conflict between threads.

Comment: This option only reduces the amount of connections to one per thread, rather than one per query.  If most of your threads only contain a single query, then this does not offer much benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft says: "...to disable OLE DB Resource Pooling, which ADO uses by default ... you can do by adding "OLE DB Services = -2" to the ADO Connection string".

Here is the link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/229564

It's very useful when a client application uses an application role.